# AS3: How to strictly test if instance is Object type?

Tags: actionscript-3, inheritance

How can I test if an instance is of the type `Object`? If I try the `is` operator, all `Object` subclasses return true as well.

```
var o:Object = {};
var s:Sprite = new Sprite();
trace(o is Object); //true
trace(s is Object); //true
```

How can I have it only return true of the instance is an `Object` superclass and not any one of it's myriad of subclasses?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [flash.utils.getQualifiedClassName(...)](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html#getQualifiedClassName()) method returns the exact **String** representation of the class for both instance and its class passed as the method argument.

```
import flash.utils.getQualifiedClassName;

var O:Object = {};
var S:Sprite = new Sprite;

var GQ:Function = getQualifiedClassName;

trace(GQ(O) == GQ(Object)); // true
trace(GQ(S) == GQ(Object)); // false
```

**UPD**: There's another way to do it, although I personally like it less. You can use the [Object.constructor](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Object.html#constructor) property which probably points to the class constructor of the given instance.

```
function isObject(target:Object):Boolean
{
    return target.constructor == Object
}

trace(isObject(O)); // true
trace(isObject(S)); // false
```